# Java - How to add elements to an array list in ascending order and count the number of pairs in the array list?

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, arraylist

Similar to my previous post, I am trying to develop a card game that:

a) Prints out the whole deck of cards

b) Adds 10 random cards in ascending order to an array list

c) Counts the number of pairs in that array list

In the class *SimpleCardGame2*, there are 2 methods that I'm having issues with which are related to parts *b* and *c*.

The *private static void addCard(ArrayList cards, Card c)* is a method that adds *Card c* into *cards.cards* and cards should be arranged from small to large.
When a new card is inserted, identify the right position so that the list is maintained the sorted order. I tried using the *.ordinal()* method to compare the elements, but I'm getting the error saying  *The field Card.rank is not visible*.

Next, the *private static int numPairs(ArrayList cards)* is a method that counts the number of card pairs in *cards*. Two cards are in a pair if they are of the same rank. Three cards of the same rank in cards is counted as 1 pair. There are 2 pairs of cards if all four cards of the same rank are in cards. My issues here are that I'm not sure how to count 3 cards of the same rank as 1 pair with the code I've written and that the error saying  *The field Card.rank is not visible* still shows up because I'm using the *.ordinal()* method to compare the card ranks.

How do I fix these errors and my code for these 2 particular methods?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleCardGame2 {
  private static void addCard(ArrayList<Card> cards, Card c) {
        for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
            if (cards.get(x) < c.rank.ordinal()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (cards.get(x) == c.rank.ordinal()) {
                return;
            }
            cards.add(x,c);
            return;
        }
        cards.add(c);
   }

  private static int numPairs(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        int count=0;
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            for (int k=j+1; k<10; k++) {
                if (cards.get(j).rank.ordinal() == cards.get(k).rank.ordinal()) {
                    count+=1;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Card> deck;  // an arraylist of Cards, representing a deck of cards

    // put a copy of each card into cards
    // The order of the cards in the array is: 
    // S2, S3, ..., SK, H2, ..., HK, C2, ..., CK, D2, ..., DK

    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
            deck.add(new Card(r,s));
        }
    }

    //
    // YOU DO NOT HAVE TO MODIFY ANYTHING BELOW
    //

    // print out the whole deck once
    System.out.println("The whole deck is:");
    System.out.println(deck);

    // randomly draw 10 cards
    // cards drawn will be removed from deck 
    MyRandom rnd = new MyRandom();
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      addCard(cards, deck.remove(rnd.nextInt(deck.size())-1));


    // print out the card drawn and the number of pairs
    System.out.print("The cards drawn are: ");
    System.out.println(cards);
    System.out.print("There are ");
    System.out.print(numPairs(cards));
    System.out.println(" pair(s) of cards.");
  }
}
```

```
public class Card {
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card (Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return suit + "" + rank;
    }

    public int compareTo(Card c) {
        int diffRank = rank.ordinal() - c.rank.ordinal();
        if (diffRank < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (diffRank > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (diffRank == 0) {
            int diffSuit = suit.ordinal() - c.suit.ordinal();
            if (diffSuit < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (diffSuit > 0) {
                return 1;
            } 
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
public enum Rank {
  TWO("2"), 
  THREE("3"), 
  FOUR("4"), 
  FIVE("5"), 
  SIX("6"), 
  SEVEN("7"), 
  EIGHT("8"),
  NINE("9"), 
  TEN("10"), 
  JACK("J"), 
  QUEEN("Q"), 
  KING("K"),
  ACE("A"); 

  private String rank;

  // Constructor
  Rank (String r) {
    rank = r;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return rank;
  }
}
```

```
public enum Suit {
    SPADE("S"), 
    HEART("H"), 
    CLUB("C"), 
    DIAMOND("D"); 

    private String suit;

    Suit (String s) {
      suit = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return suit;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyRandom {

  Random rnd;

  public MyRandom() {
//    rnd = new Random(180);
    rnd = new Random();
  }

  // generate a random integer from 1 to max
  public int nextInt(int max) {
    return rnd.nextInt(max) + 1;
  }
}
```

Here is the supposed outputs of the correct program:

```
The whole deck is:
[S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, SJ, SQ, SK, SA, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9, H10, HJ, HQ, HK, HA, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, CJ, CQ, CK, CA, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, DJ, DQ, DK, DA]
The drawn cards are: [D4, D5, S9, C10, DQ, CQ, HQ, SQ, HK, SA]
There are 2 pair(s) of cards.
```

```
The whole deck is:
[S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, SJ, SQ, SK, SA, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9, H10, HJ, HQ, HK, HA, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, CJ, CQ, CK, CA, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, DJ, DQ, DK, DA]
The drawn cards are: [D2, D5, H9, S9, H10, HJ, DK, HK, SK, CA]
There are 2 pair(s) of cards.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the first error is that the variable `rank` in class `Card` is `private`(only accessible from within the class `Card`).
There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Make it `public`(accessible from everywhere). This might be disadvantageous because that also means that the rank could be changed from everywhere in your program, but it is easier to implement and shouldn't be a problem for you I guess:

```
public class Card {
    public Rank rank;
    …
}
```

2. Add a `public` getter function which would only allow reading, but not changing the value:

```
public class Card {
    private Rank rank;
    …
    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
}
```

In the latter option you would also have to change the access from `c.rank` to `c.getRank()`.

About your second problem:
I think it would be the easiest to just count the occurence of each rank and divide it by two, so you get for each rank the amount of pairs, then you can sum those up and you are done:

```
int pairs = 0;
for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
    int cardsWithThisRank = 0;
    for(Card c : cards) {
        if(c.rank == r) { // Or c.getRank() if you chose the second option above.
            cardsWithThisRank++;
        }
    }
    int pairsWithThisRank = cardsWithThisRank/2;
    pairs += pairsWithThisRank;
}
return pairs;
```

Comment: Option 2 got rid of the visibility error. My code for _addCard_ looks like this now:

`private static void addCard(ArrayList<Card> cards, Card c) {
     for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
      if (cards.get(x).getRank().ordinal() < c.getRank().ordinal()) {
       continue;
      }
      if (cards.get(x).getRank().ordinal() == c.getRank().ordinal()) {
       return;
      }
      cards.add(x,c);
      return;
     }
     cards.add(c);
   }
`

When I run the program, I get this error: _Index 0 out of bounds for length 0_. What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is here:  `for (int x=0; x<10; x++)`
When you add the first element, your list is empty, but you still try to go through the first 10 elements, which of course cannot be accessed. You should do something like this to ensure going only through elements that exist:
 `for (int x=0; x<cards.size(); x++)`

Comment: The program works perfectly now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would create an `ArrayList` for each of the ranks. Then iterate over the drawn cards and copy each card to the correct rank arraylist. Then you need to check that size of each rank arraylist: if the size is 2 or larger it contains a pair. Count the number of arraylists that have a size of 2 or larger and you know the number of pairs.